# Generic catch for python

Tags: python, exception

I have some extremely weird behavior that seems to result in silent exceptions. How can I write a general try catch where I can debug all exceptions. Something along the lines of:

```
try:
    # something that fails
except e:
    print e
```

A bit more about the problem at hand in detail:

I have a Django app that on my computer (Ubuntu Linux 8.10) works fine both through runserver and mod-python. On the deploy server (Ubuntu Linux 8.10) it works fine through runserver, but fails via apache in mod-python.

I have reduced the cause down to a part off the app that uses Berkeley DB (bsddb.db), and secondary keys. The callback method for secondary keys uses pickle to format the keys. It fails when I call pickle on a single value. However, it only fails when I use cPickle, and using pickle on the same values outside the callback function also works.

I just want to know why it fails with cPickle.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Exceptions are already printed by default before program termination. If you want to send the error somewhere else (not print it) you can do this:

```
try:
    something()
except Exception as e:
    send_somewhere(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))
    raise # reraises the exception
```

note that this format using the `as` keyword is for python > 2.6. The old way was:

```
except Exception, e:
```

Comment: didn't know about the "Exception as e" change.  "Exception, e" always bugged me, nice to see it got cleaned up.

Comment: 'as' keyword is for python >= 2.6

Answer (score 5):

The [traceback module](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) is quite useful for formatting tracebacks. You can then write it to a logfile.

Answer (score 3):

Does this work? :

```
except BaseException, e:
```

Comment: You shouldn't catch `BaseException` - it includes `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt`, things you usually don't want to catch.